# C++ Operator Overload Confusion

Tags: c++

So I've created this class which can add the two values of two objects. What I don't really understand is in the operator function, does the values of numerator and denominator come from the object no1 in int main()?

```
class frac
{
    public:
        frac operator+(frac&);
        frac();
        frac(int, int);
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
};

frac frac::operator+(frac& tmp)
{
    frac tmpResult;
    tmpResult.numerator = numerator + tmp.numerator;
    tmpResult.denominator = denominator + tmp.denominator;

    return tmpResult;
}

int main()
{
    frac no1(2, 5);
    frac no2(3, 6);
    frac result = no1 + no2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not how addition of fractions works.

Comment: @TobiasSundell Comments aren't meant to answer the question.

Comment: also have a look at the FAQ on operator overloading in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1025391 (especially the section on arithmetic operators)

Comment: @Barmar I saw the comment before he answered so I assumed he only pointed out that. Didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: Carl is correct. Check out my improvement answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Class members can be accessed within class methods without specifying their origin (as if they are declared locally).

```
frac frac::operator+(frac& tmp)
{
    frac tmpResult;
    tmpResult.numerator = numerator + tmp.numerator;
    tmpResult.denominator = denominator + tmp.denominator;

    return tmpResult;
}
```

This code can be rewritten as this:

```
frac frac::operator+(frac& tmp)
{
    frac tmpResult;
    tmpResult.numerator = this->numerator + tmp.numerator;
    tmpResult.denominator = this->denominator + tmp.denominator;

    return tmpResult;
}
```

PS: I believe you meant operator overloading.

Edit: I had this urge to correct your math as you are dealing with fractions wrong.

Fraction addition (and substraction respectively) can be done like this:

```
frac frac::operator+(frac& tmp)
{
    int common_denominator = tmp.denominator * this->denominator;
    int common_numerator = tmp.numerator * this->denominator + this->numerator * tmp.denominator;

    //You can add simplification by dividing these 
    //two above with their greatest common divisor 
    //in order to avoid cases like 111/222 which can
    //be represented as 1/2. (this is optional)

    return frac(common_numerator, common_denominator)
}
```

Comment: Yup, wrote it wrong :p Just learned this today. I see! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> does the values of numerator and denominator come from the object no1 in int main()?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is defined as a member function, so it is equivalent to call

```
no1.operator+(no2);
```

You want to change the parameter type to a `const` reference, as you don't really want to modify the right hand side. And you want to fix your math.

Note you could also use a free function

```
frac operator+(const frac& lhs, const frac& rhs) { ... }
```

which seems more natural to some people (including me).

Comment: Note to newbies: If `frac::numerator` and `frac::denominator` were `private`, the free function above would be declared as `friend`.

Comment: @diegoperini Better yet, declare a member function for `operator+=` and you don't need to make the free function `operator+` a friend. Or use a library like Boost.Operators or my df.operators (see my profile for link) to generate `operator+` from `operator+=`.

Comment: (No need to be friends ...) in fact you'd define the free function like this: `inline frac operator+(frac lhs, const frac& rhs) { lhs += rhs; return lhs; }`

Comment: @moooeeeep That's not necessarily the most efficient way. That's why you use a library like df.operators :)

Comment: @DanielFrey of course there's a trade off between simplicity and efficiency. Mostly simplicity wins on this, I think.

Comment: @moooeeeep `class frac : df::commutative_addable< frac > { ... };` sounds simple enough to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

**YES.** Values of numerator and denominator come from Object no 1.

For your understanding, you can also write it as:

```
frac result = no1.operator+( no2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main() could be rewritten to be more explicit:

```
int main()
{
    frac no1(2, 5);
    frac no2(3, 6);
    frac result = no1.operator+( no2 );
    return 0;
}
```

This code is equivalent, but could be easier to understand which object pointer passed as this into operator+

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your mathematical errors ...

When you declare an overloaded operator as a member function, the first parameter is assumed to be `this`.  That is, `no1 + no2` is just shorthand for `no1.operator+(no2)`.  Thus, the function sees `numerator` and `denominator` from the current `no1` object (since it is on the left).

You could, alternatively, declare the function this way:

```
class frac
{
    // class declaration
    friend frac operator+(const frac& lhs, const frac& rhs);
};

frac operator+(const frac& lhs, const frac& rhs)
{
    // implement fraction addition for lhs + rhs
}
```